# Problem in integrating CQA with Bot Framework Composer (Err: Self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Tags: node.js, npm, botframework, httprequest, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to integrate the Custom Question Answering Service knowledge base with Bot Framework Composer. I am facing the below issue when trying to send a http request to CQA endpoint from Bot Framework Composer.
"Error: Request to URL failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain".

Also, facing the same problem when trying to install a package from package manager of Bot Framework Composer
"self-signed certificate in certificate chain"

I tried to send the http request from postman and getting response correctly, but the same http request from Bot Framework Composer is throwing this error.

Also, package is installed when I tried from command prompt but am getting the error when tried to install any package from package manager of Bot Framework Composer.

Somewhere I found that this issue can be fixed in development environment by adding an environment variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'. But adding this variable in runtime settings of Bot Framework Composer haven't solved the issue. Please help me understand on how to disable ssl verification in Bot Framework Composer tool.

Could you please help to understand the possible reason and a way to fix this issue?

Comment: If you set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'` it in the environment/terminal first and then launch Composer from that window; does that work? Or is that what you were doing?

Comment: As this is Dev Env, I have set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' and launched composer from the same window. The issue is resolved now. Thank you So much for your inputs. 
Could you also help me with the details on how to set up the application (Bot Framework Composer) to see the self-signed certificates, for higher environments?

Comment: I'm not an expert on certificates, but I _believe_ you can retrieve the self signed cert, install on machine that is running Composer. I don't believe you have to do anything additional in Composer.